# Filter out text from a data frame

Tags: python

[image]I have a lot of excel files from which I want to create a big dataframe.
In top of each excel file there is some text and therefore I remove it using skiprows.

As I have several rows with empty cells, I use np.nan and dropna. The code until now works as intended but the first three rows of the data frame contains text (the remaining rows contain numbers) and I need to remove the last two rows of the three. I would like to keep the first row for the variable name. Unfortunately, row 1 and row 2 contains more or less the same text. Row 3 contains text that is very different from row 1 and 2

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_excel = (pd.read_csv(f,skiprows= 1, sep=',', encoding="latin-1") for f in all_files)
df = pd.concat(df_excel, ignore_index=True)
df['Variable1'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(subset = ["Variable1"], inplace=True)
```

My question is whether it is possible to filter out the rows marked with yellow for every excel file I use in the concat function.

Comment: Can you provide example of data you have with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for your edited question:(remove yellow rows which as I understand are the first 2 for all excel files)

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

# Define a function to filter out the yellow rows
def filter_yellow_rows(df):
    # Assuming yellow rows are the first two rows, you can adjust this as needed
    return df.iloc[2:]

# Read and filter each Excel file
df_excel = (filter_yellow_rows(pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=1, sep=',', encoding="latin-1")) for f in all_files)

# Concatenate the filtered DataFrames
df = pd.concat(df_excel, ignore_index=True)

# Perform the remaining operations on 'Variable1'
df['Variable1'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
df.dropna(subset=["Variable1"], inplace=True)
```

Answer for your first unedited question(how to filter last two rows)
short answer:

```
# Filter out the last two rows
df = df.iloc[:-2]
```

long answer incase you or future readers get confused:

```
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_excel = (pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=1, sep=',', encoding="latin-1") for f in all_files)
df = pd.concat(df_excel, ignore_index=True)

# Replace empty strings with NaN in 'Variable1'
df['Variable1'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)

# Drop rows with NaN in 'Variable1'
df.dropna(subset=["Variable1"], inplace=True)

# Filter out the last two rows
df = df.iloc[:-2]

# Reset the index
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi @Cem thanks for your input. I can't get it to work. I have tried to update my question to make it easier for other to understand.

Comment: @Jonathan do you want to remove the first 2 rows for every file?

Comment: Hi @Cem. Yes I would like to remove the two lines marked by yellow from each of the files.

Comment: Ok, I added a new answer based on your current description of your problem. Let me know if this works, or describe your request-problem further please.